# If $\ker f=\ker g$ and $\mbox{im} f=\mbox{im}g$, does it yield $g=\lambda f$ for some $\lambda$?

Tags: linear-algebra

The question is, really, contained in the title : let $f$ and $g$ be 2 linear functions on $\mathbb R^n$, if we suppose that $\ker f=\ker g$ and $\mbox{im} f=\mbox{im}g$, does it yield $g=\lambda f$ for some $\lambda$? Is it at least true when $n=2$ ?

Comment: Not with lambda being a scalar.

Comment: but what it yields is $g = u f$ with $u \in GL(im f)$

Comment: it does work if $n=1$ tho

Answer (score 2):

What about

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix} \text{ and } B=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}?$$

Or $$C=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\
 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix} \text{ and }
D=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1\\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$ in dimension $2$?

Comment: Ok, I need then to be more precise: is it true when n=2 and f non bijective? (Now, I have the answer for ≥3, thanks to @mathcounterexamples.net)

Comment: The answer is still negative. See updated answer.

Comment: I don't understand:  Im E\neq Im F in your example, since Im E=vect(e_2) and Im F=vect(e_1+e_2)

Comment: Answer updated..

Comment: There must be something I can't see, for in the updated example one has again Im E\neq Im F, since Im E=vect (e_1+e_2) and Im F=vect(e_1+2e_2). In fact, when n=2, the property holds for dim\ker f=1 implies \dim Imf= 1, and hence every x can be expressed as x_1.u+x_2.v, where \ker f=\ker g=vect u and \im f=\im g=vect v. One can then write: f(x)=x_2f(v)=x_2a.v, and similarly g(x)=x_2.g(v)=x_2.b.v, which yields g(x)=\frac{b}{a}f(x).

Answer (score 2):

No.

If $f$ and $g$ are bijective, then $f$ and $g$ satisfy the above conditions.

Answer (score 1):

No. Let $n=2$ and $f$ the diagonl matrix $f=diag(1,1)$ and $g$ the diagonal matrix $g=diag(1,2)$